# AQL - How to show PK in a SELECT

Tags: aerospike

How do I include the PK when doing a AQL select?

Example:

SELECT * from test.users

Returns:

FirstName, LastName etc

What I really want to know is the PK or key so I can delete a row. How can I include the PK in a SELECT AQL statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Aerospike does not store the actual primary key in the database. It stores the 20-byte digest (hash of the key) by default. This will be a huge saving for the large keys. However, in the latest version, this can be changed by the put() operation to store the key also. But the AQL client is not enhanced yet to exploit this fact. I will file an internal ticket for this enhancement.

In the mean time...

1. option-1 : you can take a backup of your data which will also dump the digests (hash of key) in base64 encoding format. You can use those digests to delete the records.
2. option-2 : if you write scan code using C/Java or any API, you will get the list of digests too. You can use them to delete the records.

Comment: How do I write the PK with the Java API? I'm currently calling "client.put(null, key, binsArray);" (client is type com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient, key is type com.aerospike.client.Key, binsArray is 
com.aerospike.client.Bin[]). Do I just add another bin into binsArray for the key? If so, what do I use for the bin name? "PK"?

Comment: I figured it out. Sort of. I set the write policy "sendKey" attribute to true and now I can see the PK column in the AQL shell. But I still can't do a "select * from <set> where PK = '<value>' ". Always get a "record not found" result.

Comment: Yes, setting the sendKey attribute in the write policy is the correct thing to do. Looks like you are using the wrong query. It should be "select * from <namespace>.<set> where PK='<value>'" . You might have already figured this out

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. When I wrote "<set>", I was implying it also contained the namespace (I agree this wasn't clear). The query works if PK is type STRING, but not if I'm using a byte array as my key, in which case I've determined, using the "explain select..." command, that the PK type is BASE64_DIGEST. I've got a topic here that is going nowhere -- https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aql-select-with-pk/3314

Answer (score 2):

To DELETE the data from the sets - To delete a record from the set, you could use scanAll API which iterates through all the records and delete. During scanCallback call it gets the digest key for each record and deletes. Here is the reference link

> http://www.aerospike.com/community/labs/deleting_sets_and_data.html

Once we have extended functionality of retrieving primary index through AQL then you can retrieve primary index key which you have created but make sure you have stored key by calling **sendKey** attribute of **WritePolicy** class.
SendKey sends user defined key in addition to hash digest on a record put. By default it's not sent.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

create extra bin to save primary key and index it. Then you can retrieve this primary key using AQL statement.

Comment: How to create bin using aql?

Comment: @SureshParmar When you save data that has extra bin and related data, It's automatically created it.

Comment: thanks for info...i need little more help.I want to go with aerospike but i'm not sure at some certain point.I have multiple columns having map and list data types. my requirement is to store data in map and retrieve data from map. and addition also happening in map.Second thing is while retrieving data i need to check multiple bins in where clause. so how it would be convenient for me? pls reply asap. and thanks buddy. :)

Comment: You can use the 'where' only the primary key. If you want to use 'where' clause for other bins, you have to create secondary index for that bin.

Comment: okay but it is suggestable to create secondry index on frequently changing records. For Ex . i have map like app_day_count({ fb : 5 , wh : 6}) so in this count is increasing. 

And one more thing i am trying to understand is in this query ' INSERT INTO user_profile.west (PK,location,last_activity) VALUES ('cookie_100','MA',342) '. how can i retrieve PK values?