# Aerospike reverse hash PK

Tags: aerospike

I have to perform a full scan and get the PK result as well.
I know that the PK is not stored by default and I am pretty sure I did not store that in my persistence query.
I also know that what is stored is a hash of the key to avoid large keys.

I got that information from: [AQL - How to show PK in a SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611748/aql-how-to-show-pk-in-a-select)

Now, is there a way to reverse engineer the hash and get the PK?

Comment: The only chance here (if you cannot reconstruct like Ronen proposed) seems to be to a) to brute force hashes e.g. if you are using numeric ids or b) apply a logic that will store the key next time you use it (e.g. on next user login, when key is using emailadress).

Comment: I thought on that a) item as well but PKs are generated based on BSON ObjectId. So I don't think this is a possibility :/
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to reverse engineer the digest into the original PK, unfortunately. Can you deduce it from the data that's in the bins? The default policy regarding key is to use the digest only, rather than send the PK, because that takes extra space that you may not intend to use.